# How to get penultimate row from dataset in ssrs?

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc

In **SSRS**, if i can select first row using = `First(Fields!PropertyName.Value,"Dataset1")`  and last row element by using =`Last(....)`.

Can someone please let me know how can we select **penultimate** element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do this straightforward by inserting custom vb code in report. I am not sure if you will return to this question so thinking in a quick workaround I come with this:

Add a row number to the dataset query, you can achieve this using [ROW_NUMBER()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms186734(v=sql.120).aspx) function.

```
select
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order by Region) as row,
   *
from CTE
```

Now you can use the [lookup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210531.aspx) function provided by SSRS. With this function I am retrieving the Quantity value for the penultimate row.

```
=Lookup(Last(Fields!row.Value, "DataSet2")-1,Fields!row.Value,Fields!Qty.Value,"DataSet2")
```

I find the last row number and substract one to get the penultimate, when row is found I get the Quantity column value, `Fields!Qty.Value` in my case.